# Make div CSS "display: table-cell" only as wide as text in the div

Tags: html, css

I asked this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31174321/css-table-cell-alignment-and-ellipsis-not-working) yesterday to get the ellipsis working in my test form.

However, I now have another issue that I cannot solve, that relates to the answer I put in place.

When I have the users data displayed in a small preview, the ellipsis takes effect and is displayed to the user. This is done by using display: table-cell in the HTML. As shown below:

[image]

When the user views the same code in a larger modal window, the ellipsis is no longer in effect as there is room to display the users data. However, this makes the `Data di completamento` (`resumeStyleFinishDateLabel25`) too wide, as shown below:

[image]

**How do I change the CSS so that the div of the** `Data di completamento` **is only as wide as the text** `Data di completamento` **and is positioned next to the start date -** `01/2009`**?** The text in the div can be different languages, meaning different text lengths, so I cannot use a fixed width to the div.

I have tried changing the CSS display from `table` to `inline-block`, but this disables the effect of the ellipsis. I have done some reading of CSS forums and SO threads, but I cannot think of a way to solve this myself.

I am hoping that someone can show me.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="resumeStyleStandardTableRow25">
    <div class="resumeStyleStandardLabels25">Decorrenza</div>
    <div class="resumeStyleStandardLabelContent25">
        <div class="table_ellipsis">
            <div class="resumeStyleDateStartContent25">01/2009</div>
            <div class="resumeStyleFinishDateLabel25">
                <div class="ellipsis">Data di completamento</div>
            </div>
            <div class="resumeStyleDateFinishContent25">
                <div class="ellipsis_finishDate">11/2011 (2 anni, 10 mesi)</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.resumeStyleStandardTableRow25 {
    display: table-row;
}

.resumeStyleStandardLabels25 {
    direction: ltr;
    display: table-cell;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 25px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 2px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    text-align: right;
    vertical-align: top;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.resumeStyleStandardLabelContent25 {
    direction: ltr;
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 25px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 2px;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100%;
}

.table_ellipsis {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

.resumeStyleDateStartContent25 {
    direction: ltr;
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 2px;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    
    width: 75px;
}

.resumeStyleFinishDateLabel25 {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
    direction: ltr;
    display: table-cell;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 2px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    text-align: right;
    vertical-align: top;

    background-color: lime;

}

.ellipsis {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.resumeStyleDateFinishContent25 {
    direction: ltr;
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 2px;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;


}

.ellipsis_finishDate {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;

    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Hello again, I think you're on the right track, try adding `max-width:100%;` along with the `display:inline-block;` and [see](http://jsfiddle.net/f36pkb0o/).

Comment: Hey Pangloss, using `max-width:100%;` and `display:inline-block;` disables the eplissis - otherwise the larger view looks ok.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/f36pkb0o/ it seems to be OK, here on Firefox.

Comment: Pangloss, my apologies, this does work - kind of! When I stretch the result  fiddle widow to the maximum width, the `11/2011 (2 anni, 10 mesi)` in yellow is positioned far to the right of the `Data di completamento` in lime. How do I also align the `11/2011 (2 anni, 10 mesi)` to the immediate left of the `Data di completamento`? Using your code, I have tried to fix this myself, but I cannot. Any suggestions?

Comment: I see, try adding `width:100%;` or inline style `style="width:100%;"` to that far right ***table cell*** which contains `11/2011 (2 anni...` , again the fiddle has only part of the whole table code it won't work properly at the moment.

Comment: Pangloss, I have tried that and a few other things, but the div is stubborn and remains  far to the right.

Comment: I realized that we can't do the `width` tricks on fixed table layout, however there is another way to do it with `flexbox`, I suggested as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use CSS3 **`flexbox`** in this case, it supports `ellipsis` very well, and makes the markup much simpler too. Browser support **IE10+**.

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/cxpj7zaz/** [resize the output frame and see]

---

```
<div class="flexbox">
    <div class="item">Decorrenza 01/2009</div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="ellipsis">Data di completamento</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="ellipsis">11/2011 (2 anni, 10 mesi)</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
.flexbox {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}
.item {
    min-width: 0;
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}
.item:nth-child(1) { /*DO NOT SHRINK*/
    -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
        -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
            flex: 0 0 auto;
}
.ellipsis {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Pangloss, thanks once again. that solution works great.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `width: 100%;` for `.table_ellipsis` you should use `width: auto;`.

Working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1pLs9ork/):

```css
.resumeStyleStandardTableRow25 {
    display: table-row;
}

.resumeStyleStandardLabels25 {
    direction: ltr;
    display: table-cell;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 25px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 2px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    text-align: right;
    vertical-align: top;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.resumeStyleStandardLabelContent25 {
    direction: ltr;
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 25px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 2px;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100%;
}

.table_ellipsis {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: auto;
}

.resumeStyleDateStartContent25 {
    direction: ltr;
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 2px;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;

    width: 75px;
}

.resumeStyleFinishDateLabel25 {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
    direction: ltr;
    display: table-cell;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 2px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    text-align: right;
    vertical-align: top;

    background-color: lime;

}

.ellipsis {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.resumeStyleDateFinishContent25 {
    direction: ltr;
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 2px;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;


}

.ellipsis_finishDate {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;

    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="resumeStyleStandardTableRow25">
    <div class="resumeStyleStandardLabels25">Decorrenza</div>
    <div class="resumeStyleStandardLabelContent25">
        <div class="table_ellipsis">
            <div class="resumeStyleDateStartContent25">01/2009</div>
            <div class="resumeStyleFinishDateLabel25">
                <div class="ellipsis">Data di completamento</div>
            </div>
            <div class="resumeStyleDateFinishContent25">
                <div class="ellipsis_finishDate">11/2011 (2 anni, 10 mesi)</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: wazaaaap, thanks for the answer, but using `width: auto;` disables the ellipsis, so I cannot use your suggestion.